# It`s possible to calculate time complexity of Shader algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, opengl, graphics, time-complexity, computer-science

I'm currently attending an algorithm analysis class and we were given group work. The Professor demanded we choose some field in computer science, pick an algorithm and prove the asymptotic limits (at least O(N)).

So me and my colleague chose to do a computer graphics algorithm, more specifically a lighting volume algorithm.

But all the code analysed by algorithm analysis books runs on the CPU. Code produced in OpenGL runs on the GPU, which can not guarantee linearity, since it is made of several other CPUs running in parallel.

Does that behavior influence the calculation? Could someone help me figure out where to start?

This piece of code is extracted from GPU Gems 3: 
[Volumetric Light Scattering as a Post-Process](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpugems/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch13.html).

```
float4 main(float2 texCoord : TEXCOORD0) : COLOR0  
{  
  // Calculate vector from pixel to light source in screen space.  
   half2 deltaTexCoord = (texCoord - ScreenLightPos.xy);  
  // Divide by number of samples and scale by control factor.  
  deltaTexCoord *= 1.0f / NUM_SAMPLES * Density;  
  // Store initial sample.  
   half3 color = tex2D(frameSampler, texCoord);  
  // Set up illumination decay factor.  
   half illuminationDecay = 1.0f;  
  // Evaluate summation from Equation 3 NUM_SAMPLES iterations.  
   for (int i = 0; i < NUM_SAMPLES; i++)  
  {  
    // Step sample location along ray.  
    texCoord -= deltaTexCoord;  
    // Retrieve sample at new location.  
   half3 sample = tex2D(frameSampler, texCoord);  
    // Apply sample attenuation scale/decay factors.  
    sample *= illuminationDecay * Weight;  
    // Accumulate combined color.  
    color += sample;  
    // Update exponential decay factor.  
    illuminationDecay *= Decay;  
  }  
  // Output final color with a further scale control factor.  
   return float4( color * Exposure, 1);  
}
```

I think the asymptotic limit would be a function of the samples.
Something that also needs to be taken into account are the 4 physical equations needed to generate the shader. Thanks in advance for all the community help!

Comment: If you are interested in deeper GPU complex analysis see this: https://www.mimuw.edu.pl/~ps209291/kgkp/slides/scan.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
uniform float exposure;
uniform float decay;
uniform float density;
uniform float weight;
uniform vec2 lightPositionOnScreen;
uniform sampler2D myTexture;
const int NUM_SAMPLES = 100 ;
void main()
{   
C1  vec2 deltaTextCoord=vec2(gl_TexCoord[0].st-lightPositionOnScreen.xy);                          
C2      vec2 textCoo = gl_TexCoord[0].st;                                                                         
C3      deltaTextCoord *= 1.0 /  float(NUM_SAMPLES) * density;                                        
C4      float illuminationDecay = 1.0;                                                                                 
n       for(int i=0; i < NUM_SAMPLES ; i++)     {                                          
C5              textCoo -= deltaTextCoord;                                                    
C6          vec4 sample = texture2D(myTexture, textCoo );                        
C7                     sample *= illuminationDecay * weight;                                   
C8              gl_FragColor += sample;                                                      
C9              illuminationDecay *= decay;                                                    
                                                }
C10                 gl_FragColor *= exposure;  
}
```

`f(n)  =∑_(i=0)^n〖(C_5+ C_6+ C_7+ C_8+ C_9)〗  + C_1  + C_2  + C_3  + C_4  + C_10`

`(C_5+ C_6+ C_7+ C_8+ C_9 )=K_1`

`(C_1  + C_2  + C_3  + C_4  + C_10)=K_2`

Therefore:
`f(n)= Cp* K_1*n+ K_2`

Being Cp the number of pixels.

Which is
`f(n)= θ(n) for each pixel.`

@dv1729 Comment really helped in the course of the development of the University Homework.

This Proves the Computer Graphics Algorithms analysis can be very deceptive, because we all know how hard on hardware this kind of post-processing is, but reviewing the code shows us an Asymptotic limit that is indeed very low. The constants here can be very high and the profound math behind physically based volumetric light sccatering, can go unnoticed.

Answer (score 4):

The complexity of an algorithm does not change with the number of processing elements (for a finite number of processors). A polynomial time algorithm is polynomial time, whether on the CPU or GPU. To put it another way, n<sup>2</sup> is no different from (n/320)<sup>2</sup>, as "n" approaches infinity.

The complexity of the algorithm doesn't change; the *execution time* does. But this is true of lots of complexity. Quick sort and merge sort have the same nLog(n) complexity, but quick sort is on average faster in practice.

Asymptotic limits are not the end-all-be-all of performance.

Comment: Yes, I just talked to some teacher, and they say the problem will be understanding some OpenGL functions.In ordinary code, all we have easy to read complexity, like atributions, loops(Summations)... But what complexity this line has, for instance:`half3 color = tex2D(frameSampler, texCoord); ` this gonna be a very hard job, and I hope I come here a couple months later with the full result of the work to post it!If somoene can give me a hand on this piece of code described in the question I would immensly appreciate!

Comment: @mandre96: "*But what complexity this line has, for instance*" Complexity with respect to *what*? Complexity is not an absolute value; it's always relative to some `n`. So what is `n`? The size of the texture? The texture coordinate? On which hardware? Answering that question for texture accesses requires knowing the algorithm being used to fetch the texel.

Comment: I think N is the any important parameter that changes the resulting cost. Of course, this is not 100% objective, but from my point of view it should be the one of my answer.

Comment: "Answering that question for texture accesses requires knowing the algorithm being used to fetch the texel." The cost of a texture access has a maximum execution time associated, therefore, is O(1). Of course, there will be a difference between hitting the cache and missing it, but in the worse case scenario it is bounded by the global memory access latency, therefore it's O(1)

Comment: @dv1729: That's not how [asymptotic analysis works](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis). You may *want* it to work that way all you like, but that doesn't change how it actually works.

Comment: @NicolBolas That's exactly how it works. If you are worried about not having a "N", check algorithms that don't depend on just one thing, for example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm If you are worried about "The cost of a texture access is O(1)" see any CPU sorting complexity analysis, all of them are based on that: a fixed number of reads and writes to RAM are O(1). Insertion sort, for example, have an average and worst case performance of O(N²) because it makes N² swaps, and one swap is 2 reads and 2 writes to memory (a constant amount of memory accesses)

Comment: It is hard to belive that a Load Texture function, something so demanding, executes in constant time, you sure ain't O(✓n)?

Comment: @mandre96: Constant time relative to what? To the size of the texture? In that case, yes, an array access will be O(1) relative to the texture's size. Given a texture's size, and a pointer to where the start of the texture is, the fetch logic can compute the exact memory address of that texel in constant time relative to the size. Following this is a memory access, which will be constant time relative to the texture's size. Therefore, the entire operation will be *constant time*, relative to the texture's size. Constant time is not the same thing as ***fast***.

Comment: At leat where I study, we say constant time, when an algorithm executes independently  of the input(which is N, and in this case the size of the Texture).We express that with O(1).That's why I thougth that @dv1729  way of thinking is very insidious, I hope you guys can clarify me.

Answer (score 0):

All lines of code implies a constant execution time (they don't imply loops or recursive calls or anything like that). However, the lines inside the loop are executed NUM_SAMPLES times. Therefore, the execution time of one shader invocation is going to be:

O(NumSamples)

Since this shader is executed once per pixel the total execution time is going to be:

O(NumSamples * ResolutionX * ResolutionY)

Keep in mind that Nicol Bolas is right, the complexity of the algorithm hasn't changed, it has the same if it is executed on the CPU, but it would be slower for hardware-related issues.

In a deeper analysis you could analyze the usage of each GPU core and the speedup over the CPU, but in this simple code... It doesn't matter much since usage would probably be very close to 100%. In any case, to analyze this you'll need to understand both GPU hardware architecture and general algorithm costs.